# How to make semi-glossy emissions material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, workflow

How can i make a material that looks semi-glossy, but the "glossy" accents are being generated from emissions, rather than being generated by reflections from light sources outside the object?

Thanks!

Edit:

[image]

This is the current material.  Here is the node setup:

[image]

Here i have added some highlights in Photoshop:

[image]

I want the highlights to be emissions (rather than dependent upon outside light sources), if possible! (Although it would be interesting to see how the nodes would be set up for adding an environment-dependent gloss to the emissions material.) It does not have to be true-to-life; the goal is to simply add a layer of depth/presence/interest to the material.

Comment: Can you add an image that illustrates what you are after?

Comment: I want a material that *looks* "glossy" no matter what the outside light sources are, a material that would have glossy-looking accents in complete absence of an outside light source.  I will look for an illustration !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be what you are looking for:

[image]

Its pretty much self explanatory: You use the facing node to add shadows and glossy reflections. If you need the gloss to be face-on, you just have to invert the ramp.